Customer authentication with SSO for Shopware
I have a shopware installation running on my server. I want to use this as a store system for my colleagues at my company so that they can easily reorder office supplies. To simplify things for them, i want the login to work via the windows identy platform from entra id or similar.
The problem is, i can only find solutions for the authentication via SSO for the backend, not for the frontend.
How can i implement this in the frontend for the customers?

i think what you are searching for is: https://store.shopware.com/moorl48017823224m/login-mit-facebook-google-keycloak-uvm-oauth-2.0.html
They are also providing microsoft and custom auth.
Hope that helps.
